# Inscribe a rectangle inside an ellipse

Tags: geometry, rectangles

A rectangle is to be inscribed inside a horizontal ellipse (whose major or minor axis is parallel to x axis). Is the horizontal orientation of the rectangle (two sides parallel to x axis) the only possibility to inscribe it?

Comment: I thought the original version of your question was more interesting.

Comment: Agree. In retrospect I feel the same way. But the revised version is what was relevant to a math problem I am working on. I think I got all the insights I needed from the original version, so should I revert back to the original version?

Comment: That is up to you :-)

Comment: Reverted it back because the beauty in math problems is something that attracts me to maths. Thanks for pointing it out TonyK!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. You can place it horizontally or vertically.

Comment: Do you have a proof? Or an argument to convince for this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Actually there are infinite ways to inscribe a rectangle in a regular ellipse but orientation is same for all that rectangles i.e horizontal orientation. Length of the side of rectangle varies from 0 to length of the major axis of the ellipse, accordingly breadth of rectangle varies from length of the minor axis to 0. That is if you take an ellipse with major axis 'a' and minor axis 'b', length of rectangle varies from 0 to a and breadth varies from b to 0 respectively.

Comment: Hi you are right. But sorry, I forgot to mention the condition that two sides of the inscribed rectangle has to pass through the foci of the ellipse. Edited the question just now to reflect this. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the condition *two of its sides pass through the foci of the ellipse*.
You only need

> Any conics is uniquely determined by 5 points on it.

Start with your inscribed rectangle $ABCD$, construct a line $\ell$ parallel to one of its sides, say $AB$, passing through the center of the rectangle $O$. Let $\ell$ intersect your ellipse at some point $E$. It is clear you can construct another ellipse having $O$ as center, passing through $A,B,C,D$ and $E$  and either the major or the minor axis of it is $\ell$. Because any conics is uniquely determined by any 5 points on it. The new ellipse constructed is the same as your old ellipse. This means $\ell$ is either the major or the minor axis of your original ellipse!

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your choice of the point E. It just sounds too convenient to choose it on the ellipse itself.

Comment: So your claim says that "if you pick 5 points from a known Conic, you can redraw the conic", right?

Comment: Does the claim include that, "give me any 5 points, and I will draw you a Conic (ellipse in this case) passing through them?

Comment: Ellipse is a simple closed curve. It separate the plane into 2 components, the inside and the outside. If you start from any point inside (say the center $O$ of the rectangle) and construct a rate start from $O$ in any direction. It will hit the ellipse at some point. If you choose the ray parallel to one of the sides, you get the point $E$.

Comment: sorry still not following why doing this is important.

Comment: Look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html) on wolfram why five points determine a conic. In particular, the equation there how to express you conic in terms of the coordinates of the 5 other points. In short, given any 5 general points, you can always draw a unique conic through them (though sometimes the conic may be degenerate like becoming a pair of lines).

Comment: +1 for elegance. Of course the location of $E$ will depend on what ellipse the rectangle is inscribed in, but no matter what that ellipse is, its axes turn out to be parallel to the sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let the ellipse be $x^2+ay^2=b$.  Let the centre of the rectangle be $(c,d)$, and the length of its diagonals be $2r$.  The points on the rectangle are all distance $r$ from $(c,d)$, and two points are directly opposite the other two.

So there is an angle $\alpha$ that gives the coordinates of $P1$ below, and the opposite point $P2$ follows.

$$P1(c-r\cos\alpha,d-r\sin\alpha),\\P2(c+r\cos\alpha,d+r\sin\alpha),\\P3(c-r\cos\beta,d-r\sin\beta),\\P4(c+r\cos\beta,d+r\sin\beta)$$

Feed these points into the equation for the ellipse.

P1: $(c-r\cos\alpha)^2+a(d-r\sin\alpha)^2=b$

P2: $(c+r\cos\alpha)^2+a(d+r\sin\alpha)^2=b$

Subtract P1 from P2, divide by 4. The difference is $cr\cos\alpha+adr\sin\alpha=0$.

Repeat for $P3$ and $P4$ to get $cr\cos\beta+adr\sin\beta=0$

If $cd\ne0$, then $\tan\alpha=-ad/c=\tan\beta$, so it is not a rectangle.

If $c=0$ and $d\ne 0$ then $\sin\alpha=0=\sin\beta$.  Similar if $d=0\ne c$.

If $c=d=0$ then $r^2(\cos^2\alpha+a\sin^2\alpha)=b=r^2(\cos^2\beta+a\sin^2\beta)$ so $\sin^2\alpha=\sin^2\beta$, and it is a rectangle with horizontal sides.

Comment: This answer passed right above my head. Can you please shed some light on how and why you chose the vertices of the rectangles like that (in terms of sin and cos)? Thanks.

Comment: The diagonals of the rectangle each have an orientation with respect to the $x$ axis. Each orientation can be described by an angular value: $0$ if the line is parallel to the axis, otherwise the angle at the $x$-intercept. We name those two angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We also use the name $(c,d)$ for the point where the diagonals intersect. All of the rest follows from that. For example, the difference in the $x$ coordinates of $P_2$ and $P_1$ is $2r \cos \alpha$, and so for $P_2$ and $(c,d)$ the difference is $r \cos \alpha$.

Comment: If $cd \ne 0$, then $-ad/c = \cot \alpha$, I think. The proof still works, however, since now $\cot \alpha = \cot \beta$.